# Catch all url route that allows query parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using ui-router, is there a way to capture a path that contains forward slashes and query parameters?

Let's say there's the catch-all rule in the state configuration:

```
var exState = {
    url: '/example/*path',
    ...
};
$stateProvider.state(exState);
```

and then point my browser to

```
/example/test1?var1=a&var2=b/test2?var3=c&var4=d/
```

I now see that the forward slashes get encoded:

```
test1?var1=a&var2=b%2Ftest2%3Fvar3&var4=d%2F
```

and `$stateParams.path` is `test1` - not what I wanted. Is it possible to get the actual 'raw' path for further processing while avoiding the automatic query parameter capturing which ui-router is doing here?

Comment: Why don't you put a watch on the variable that controls transition ?

Comment: @hasH: sorry, I don't follow. Could you elaborate? Do you mean watch `$stateChangeSuccess` and and its `toParams` - which has the same value btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this but you'll need to use Regex with your URL state, this is from the UI-Router Guide (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing):

```
Regex Parameters

A bonus to using curly brackets is the ability to set a Regular Expression rule for the parameter:

// will only match a contactId of one to eight number characters
url: "/contacts/{contactId:[0-9]{1,8}}"
Examples:

'/user/{id:[^/]*}' - Same as '/user/{id}' from the previous example.

'/user/{id:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}}' - Similar to the previous example, but only matches if the   id parameter consists of 1 to 8 hex digits.

'/files/{path:.*}' - Matches any URL starting with '/files/' and captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.

'/files/*path' - Ditto. Special syntax for catch all.`
```

This one should catch your url and the parameter string: **'/files/{path:.*}' - Matches any URL starting with '/files/' and captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.**

**EDIT:** After capturing the the rest of the URL in the `path` parameter you'll need to URL decode in order to regain the `/` & `?` and anything else encoded.  You can use `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: I thought I just applied the very same catch all rule that was in the documents. The problem - I assume - is that ui-router uses a regex to capture query parameters even in the catch all rule. I can capture an url like `/example/test1/test2/test3/test4/` just fine - problem are those query parameters. The wiki also states that you cannot put forward slashes in regex'es. My problem is that the url path is non-hierarchical and `example` could be followed by 2 or 20 consecutive sections - that is why I want the raw path to myself, so I can manage it by myself.

Comment: To give you a better understanding, my question is related to another issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224543/non-hierarchical-url-scheme-for-a-dashboard-application.

Comment: If the foward slashes and anything else get encode, can you not decode them?  Is path missing everything beyond `test1`?

Comment: Yes, the value of `$stateParams.path` is `test1`.

Comment: So the `?` is causing the problem.  Can you try encoding the whole string yourself prior to attaching it to the URL?  Notice that the other `?` is encoded, so the first one is being treated as the querystring, what you want it everything to be a part of the path.